# NameError: name 'ana' is not defined

Tags: python

Sou iniciante no python e precisava fazer um programa que verificasse se uma palavra dada é palindromo. O programa então seria:

```
#encoding: utf-8

palavra = input ('Palavra: ')
if palavra == palavra[::-1]:
   print ("%s é palindrome" %palavra)
else:
   print ("%s não é palindrome" %palavra)
```

O problema é que, quando tento abrir o programa pelo terminal (uso ubuntu 16.04), aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "palindrome.py", line 3, in <module>
    palavra = input ('Palavra: ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ana' is not defined
```

E eu não faço a menor ideia do que isso significa. Isso tem acontecido sempre que preciso trabalhar como variáveis tipo string no python, alguém sabe por que isso acontece?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acontece que você está tentando executar um código feito para Python 3.* usando Python 2.*. Troque **`input`** para **`raw_input`** que vai funcionar.

Provavelmente você vai precisar mudar os comentários para conseguir usar os acentos.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

palavra = raw_input ('Palavra: ')
if palavra == palavra[::-1]:
   print ("%s é palindrome" %palavra)
else:
   print ("%s não é palindrome" %palavra)
```

---

**`input()`** no Python 2.* pega o valor digitado pelo usuário e tenta "evaluar" ele (é como se tentasse interpretar a string como código propriamente dito). É a mesma coisa que fazer `eval(raw_input())`.

No Python 3.*, o `input()` faz o mesmo que o antigo `raw_input`.

Comment: a forma como ele declarou a codificação de texto do arquivo Python (`#encoding: utf-8`) funciona também. Não é preciso colocar os   `-*-` - eles só estão presentes em muitos exemplos e docuemtnações por que dessa forma a codificação também era reconhecida por versões antigas do EMACS.

Comment: Obrigado pelo complemento @jsbueno. Eu não sabia que funcionava da outra forma porque justamente sempre vejo da forma que fiz...

Comment: Ele usa uma expressão regular, e procura por `coding: codifição` na primeira ou segunda linha, com ou sem espaços depois dos dois pontos. Em Python3 assume-se que a codifiação é utf-8, tornando a linha desncessária.

Answer (score 3):

Eu Acredito que você deseje utilizar a função `raw_input`, na verdade a função `input` na versão 2.7 do python funciona de uma maneira diferente, veja um exemplo:

```
>>> d="eder"
>>> palavra = input("teste:")
teste:d
>>> palavra
'eder'
```

Ele espera algo que o python consiga interpretar no código, neste caso eu tinha declarado a variável `d` recebendo o meu nome.

vamos testar a função `raw_input` agora:

```
>>> palavra = raw_input('Palavra: ')
Palavra: eder
>>> palavra
'eder'
```

Portanto raw_input parece ser o que você precisa...